# What is the difference between np.array([val1, val2]) and np.array([[val1, val2]])?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

What is the difference between np.array([1, 2]) and np.array([[1, 2]])?
Which one of them is a matrix?
I also do not understand the output for shape of the above tensors. The former returns (2,) and the latter returns (1,2).

Comment: Do you understand what dimensions are regarding array?

Comment: Yes @AloneTogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.array([1, 2])` builds an array starting from a list, thus giving you a 1D array with the shape `(2, )` since it only contains a single list of two elements.

When using the double `[` you are actually passing a list of lists, thus this gets you a multidimensional array, or matrix, with the shape `(1, 2)`.

With the latter you are able to build more complex matrices like:

```
np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

rendering a 3x3 matrix:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9]])
```